# Fetch API with Google Directions API is not working in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, google-places-api, fetch

```
async getDirections( ) {
    let resp = await fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=13.010587,%2080.259151&destination=13.023261,%2080.277290`)
    let respJson = await resp.json();
    let points = Polyline.decode(respJson.routes[0].overview_polyline.points);
    let coords = points.map((point, index) => {
        return {
            latitude: point[0],
            longitude: point[1]
        }
    })
    this.setState({ coords: coords })
    return coords
}
```

This is my code. I am getting error as unable to fetch from google api

Comment: whats the error? what is output in the console?

Comment: I guess the url should contain user specific key

Comment: tried with key also its not coming ,failed to fetch is the error

Comment: @KarthickRaja, will you please check the answer?

Comment: that works !!!!!!

Comment: @KarthickRaja,Glad to here that :) , will you please also upvote the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no issue with your code :**

**Issue is with Google direction api, if you want to call it from client side you must use their library,**

> Google disabled JSON-P callback for Geocoding to prevent abuse. You
>   must use Google Geocoding API library to do the proper request, and
>   the purpose of reverse Geocoding must be to show an address on Google
>   Maps.

---

> Hacked - Solutions : (Use proxy server)

```
async getDirections( ) {
    var proxy_url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
    var target_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=13.010587,%2080.259151&destination=13.023261,%2080.277290';
    var google_api_key = '&key=your_google_api_key'

    let resp = await fetch(`${proxy_url}${target_url}${google_api_key}`)
    let respJson = await resp.json();
    let points = Polyline.decode(respJson.routes[0].overview_polyline.points);
    let coords = points.map((point, index) => {
        return {
            latitude: point[0],
            longitude: point[1]
        }
    })
    this.setState({ coords: coords })
    return coords
}
```